# Product's Amazon pages embedded in iframes does not appears

Tags: php, iframe

Following chunk html code works as expected:

```
<iframe src="http://www.amazon.com/"></iframe>
```

But when trying embed inner Amazon pages `http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0672329166/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_g14_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1E72BDHD1YZMPYZ2HM4Z&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=470938631&pf_rd_i=507846` nothing appears.

Firebug shows that request is well executed with a `200 OK` code.

```
<iframe src="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/..."></iframe>
```

Is there some Amazon policy involving this kind of use of their site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use [`x-frame-options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) to block their content from being loaded in frames.